# FullCalendar not rerendering correctly after being hidden

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fullcalendar

Need advice on this weird bug. I can't really explain it well, but [here's an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5LLl.jpg).
What is supposed to happen is that when the calendar is shown, those stripes denote that the user is unable to add any events unless they fill in the Location and Practitioner fields first.

FullCalendar is able to get the events but I have to resize the page to a smaller width for the events to show up correctly. After you resize the calendar works fine.

The cause of this seems to be because the parent div is hidden initially and after a button is pressed the calendar is shown.

The code looks like this:

HTML:

```
<button v-on:click="renderCalendar('new')">Show Calendar</button>
<div v-show="calendar_mode !== null">
    <FullCalendar ref="fullCalendar" defaultView="timeGridWeek" ....></FullCalendar>
</div>
```

JS:

```
renderCalendar(type) {
    this.calendar_mode = type;

    this.$nextTick(() =>  {
        console.log("rerendering")
        let calendarApi = this.$refs.fullCalendar.getApi()
        calendarApi.render();
        calendarApi.rerenderEvents()
    });
},
```

I've thought of using 'visibility' instead but the parent of this component also uses `display:none`;

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried calling the calendar.render() method after the div is shown? This should cause the calendar to re-draw

Comment: Yes, that's what the `renderCalendar()` function is for, but that still didn't work